# Google Forms Language change Issue

Tags: google-forms

I have problem changing the language in google forms.
Example i have the form:
[GoogleFormDocument](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1prpgCPOchq4FvSzsWHifIcb9P89p3UsjdtnwtakkWBk/viewform#start=openform&hl=da)

On the end of the link i have defined &hl=da which means it should be translated in danish,but this only works on mozzila firefox.In Chrome and IE11 it doesnt change the language and i dont now why and cant figure out.
Have anyone experienced this difficilty and have solution for this problem?
Btw embeding the google form in website and modificate the form its not a solution for me.
Pls help!

Answer (score 0):

&hl=da this command is ignored. You must cvhange your own account language